# Opening ASC file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, ascii, format

I'd like to open a .asc file in QGIS from this website:
[Monthly mean tropospheric NO2 from TROPOMI](http://www.temis.nl/airpollution/no2col/no2month_tropomi.php?Region=2&Year=2019&Month=05)

I suspect there's a problem with the headers or something, but can't figure it out. 
Using the Translate (convert format) gives the error: 
`not recognised as a supported file format`.

The file comes `.qz` compressed, and then looks like this:

```
TROPOMI monthly-mean tropospheric NO2 columns, version 1.0
Year 2019 Month  5, units: 1e13 molecules/cm2, undef=-999
Longitudes:  2880 bins centered on 179.9375 W to 179.9375 E  (0.125 degree steps)
Latitudes :  1440 bins centered on  89.9375 S to  89.9375 N  (0.125 degree steps)
lat=  -89.9375
-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999
[143 more rows like this, then the next latitude:]
lat=  -89.8125
-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999
[etc]
[example of some more interesting rows]
-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999-999   4   4   2   4   7
   6   6  12  -1  -2  -1   2   0 -12 -18  13  15  -1  -1  -3   1   4   4   3   6
   0   1 -10  -9   2  17  15   1   1-999  11   7  -2  25  11  -6  11  13  15  -9
  -9   4  13  -8  -8  -9 -24  11  -4  -9 -10   5   9   3  18  19  -5  -6  -6  -6
 -14 -13-999-999-999-999-999  12  12-999-999   9   9   0   0-999-999-999-999-999
```

Comment: What happens when you drag&drop?

Comment: "is not a recognised or valid data source"

Comment: I pasted a few example rows as an edit to the question, so people can see the issue without downloading and unpacking a 16 Meg file. Unfortunately I don't have an answer, though!

Comment: The  [Toms asc format](https://acd-ext.gsfc.nasa.gov/People/Ahn/v8toms/DVDdocs/format.htm) of the file is is different from the [ESRI ASCII Raster format](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm)  and not recognized by QGIS (GDAL)

Comment: Is a conversion from Toms asc to ESRI ASCII possible?

Comment: Is it possible to visualise it in python?

Comment: Not in Python, but in R  [Read ascii grid data into matrix format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634805/read-ascii-grid-data-into-matrix-format)